# Firebase Python SDK: Bulk Migrating Users across tenants within same App (Firebase/Google Cloud Identity Platform)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to do the following:

1. Authorize to project, to initialize an `App`.
2. Get all of existing tenants with `list_tenants`
3. Authorize with scope of the tenant, by `tenant_mgt.auth_for_tenant` to get `Client`
4. Create new user with most data ported over, including passwords.
5. Retrieve and define hash data for the client
6. import it to the target tenant with hash data provided (In my case this is None, the native app environemnt).
7. delete users from source tenant.

On **5**, I just cannot manage to find sources to programmatically fetch the hash key and salt for each of the tenants.

Manual lookup on the key and salt, and hardcoding it works;

```py
import base64
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import tenant_mgt
from firebase_admin.auth import import_users, delete_users, ImportUserRecord, Client, UserProvider, UserImportHash

app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
tenants = [t.tenant_id for t in tenant_mgt.list_tenants(app=app).iterate_all()]

new_users = []
for tenant in tenants:
    # auth for the tenant
    client: Client = tenant_mgt.auth_for_tenant(tenant, app=app)
    users = [u for u in client.list_users(max_results=1000).iterate_all()]
    
    if not users:
        continue
    for user in users:
        try:
            new_user = ImportUserRecord(
                uid=user.uid,
                email=user.email,
                email_verified=user.email_verified,
                display_name=user.display_name,
                photo_url=user.photo_url,
                phone_number=user.phone_number,
                disabled=user.disabled,
                custom_claims=user.custom_claims,
                user_metadata=user.user_metadata,
                provider_data=[UserProvider(
                    uid=user.uid,
                    email=user.email,
                    display_name=user.display_name,
                    photo_url=user.photo_url,
                    provider_id=user.provider_id,
                )],
                password_hash=base64.b64decode(user.password_hash),
                password_salt=base64.b64decode(user.password_salt),
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(user.uid)

        new_users.append(new_user)

    try:
        # TODO: Add a way to retrieve key/salt for each tenant
        hash_data = UserImportHash.scrypt(
            key=base64.b64decode("HARDCODED HASH KEY"),
            rounds=8,
            memory_cost=14,
            salt_separator=base64.b64decode("HARDCODED SALT"),
        )

        
        import_users(new_users, app=app, hash_alg=hash_data)
        client.delete_users([u.uid for u in users])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Failed to import users for tenant: {}".format(tenant))
        continue
```